# Drive unable to initialise,“Device Not Ready” when attempting to connecting hard drive to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have an old Seagate Barracuda 7200.7 hard drive that I am attempting to connect to a Windows 7 machine by using a USB 2.0 to IDE/SATA Adapter.(it was previously connected to an internal IDE connection untill it disapeared from the disc manager) I'm connecting things in the right order (ide, power, then usb) and the jumper settings on the drive are neutral.

I am recieving a message that the drive is not initialized. When I go into Computer Management I can see the drive (as "Disk 2, Unknown, Not Initialized"), but when I attempt to initialize it or right-click and select "Offline" It tells me that "the device is not ready".

This was my secondery drive with all my personnel files, not a bootable drive.
I can connect and read the harddrive on my smart TV from Philips, but cant recover the files from there. Any ideas how I can copy the data that I need off of this drive? Is there a third party tool available that I can use?

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with this adapter if you had another disk that "disappeared" while being connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue would occur with two major reasons

One is because of adapter. please change the adapter and check the drive

Other reason is the drive may get corrupted due to virus. You can use [recovery tool](http://www.yodot.com/hard-drive-recovery/from-not-initialized-hard-drive.html) to get recover your data and then you can format your drive.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I kept my system virus free to the best of my knowledge, the boot drive shows clean on deep system scans. The adaptor is another matter totally. I will try to get another adaptor and try this. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I agree that a virus would make the drive inaccessible.  I am torn between the helpful advice of checking the connections and the technical inaccuracy of saying a virus might be at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , it took a while but I have now tested a new adaptor and also tried the hard drive on 2 windows 7 PCs and a widows XP. The result is the non windows TV runs the disk (in read only mode) and on all windows systems it will install the drivers sucsessfully but after that the drive is not visable/accessable. Divice manager will find it but not access it, and disk manager will not see it at all. My conclussion is the MBR is broken or missing.

Any ideas about how to get into the drive outside of windows? I have seen virus protectors that will boot there own OS to fix a virus so I assume some software must be available that will do the same to recover data.

Answer (score -1):

please download software Fastcopy 2.08

write .bat to copy your data into new HDD.

if your old HHDs are FAT, you will need to change NTFS.

FAT32 transfer to NTFS file

start
cmd
c:> convert I:/fs:/ntfs

Comment: I will have a look at fastcopy but as the drive is not accessable on the PC I have the feeling it will not help. (I have no drive letter just the Disk2 on disc manager.)